# unable to create a office application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office365, officedev

I'm new in office developer platform. I'm trying to create an office application with out any add-in but the option is not visible in  `Visual Studio 2015`.

I have installed `Office Developer Tools 2015` still no option

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what Office APIs you want to work with or what kind of solution you are trying to design?  If it is not an Office COM Add-in, is it a web Add-in using the Office for JavaScript API?  Do you want to work with the desktop Office Object Models or the Office 365 REST (Microsoft Graph) APIs?

Comment: I'm in learning phase trying to explore capabilities of office 365 . I'm learning from edx.com --> So in the first lecture he told how to create simple outlook application that can read content of mail using java script objects for this i need to create an office app (with out add-in) and his visual studio has option create app but no such option in my case :(

Comment: Somehow you are missing the Apps for Office templates. I can't recall if that is an install option for Visual Studio or a separate download - it should be present in Visual Studio 2015. Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx#Apps and here: https://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins

Comment: fix formatting, add officedev tag

Answer (score -1):

You will need these tools installed on your Visual Studio environment. Can you try installing one of these two exe's please?

http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforVS2013
http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforVS2015